# Genre identification: "Honor for All" by Jon Licht and Daniel Licht

Tags: identify-this-genre

A friend and I were attempting to determine a genre for the song "Honor for All" by Jon Licht and Daniel Licht, but were unable to come up with anything fitting, as it doesn't fit into any stereotypical categories we're familiar with.

What genre would this be classified as?

**Here's a YouTube link to the song:** [Honor for all - Jon Licht and Daniel Licht](https://youtu.be/p0NFGgl7Cqs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I'd probably put this song under

- Rock

  - Progressive Rock

    - Symphonic Rock

If you're looking for more like it, maybe try Progressive Rock / Progressive Metal, there are plenty of bands that overlap the two (something like Dream Theater maybe).

Comment: It really reminds of Dream Theater, yes, even the voice is somewhat similar.